# Magento - Overload Controller Class

Tags: php, oop, magento

I've been trying to overload the `Mage_Customer_AccountController` class in a module I'm building for Magento but for some reason it's not working, my methods aren't being called even though the class is being instantiated.

In my `etc/config.xml` I've got:

```
[...]
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <mycompany_mymodule before="Mage_Customer">Mycompany_Mymodule_Override</mycompany_mymodule>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>
</frontend>
[...]
```

And in `controllers/Override/AccountController.php` I have:

```
<?php
require_once('Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php');
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Override_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController {
    /**
     * This runs if uncommented
     */
    //public function __construct() {
    //    Mage::log("THIS GETS LOGGED");
    //}

    /**
     * This should be replacing the default loginAction but doesn't run.
     */
    public function loginAction() {
        Mage::log('THIS DOES NOT GET LOGGED');
    }
}
?>
```

What I find peculiar is that the constructor above clearly runs if uncommented but the `loginAction` method doesn't run, instead the `loginAction` method from `Mage_Customer_AccountController` runs.

What I'm **actually** trying to accomplish is to stop the `AccountController` from redirecting users back to `/customer/account/login` after they log out since this module ties into an external API/service that handles users. I tried just using an observer that triggered on `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_logout` to do some logout housekeeping before redirecting users back to whatever page they were on prior to logging out but the `AccountController` steps in before the redirect to the external service and issues its own redirect to `/customer/account/login`.

If anyone has suggestions on a better way of doing this I'm all ears.

**Edit:** It appears my problem is elsewhere as the original action method I assumed was being called isn't being called at all. Instead something somewhere in Magento is issuing a redirect to `/customer/account/login` after the observer method mentioned above runs (the observer attempts to set a redirect but this gets ignored (and yes, I've checked, the URL I'm using for the redirect is most definitely not `/customer/account/login`)).

Comment: For the purpose of this example it's `Mymodule` but obviously I did a search and replace before posting.

Comment: You should have `controllers/Customer/AccountController.php` if its overriden in your local code pool. Also when you call this action `custom/account/login` then only your `public function loginAction()` will be called

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: What do you mean? I'm specifying in my `config.xml` that Magento should look for my class in `controllers/Override/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try catching event:

`customer_logout`

this event is fired in method `logout` in class `Mage_Customer_Model_Session`, and it provide the `customer` object just before call protected method `_logout` that deletes session cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Your config.xml file

```
...   
 <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <company_modulename before="Mage_Customer">Company_Modulename</company_modulename>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
...
```

And create a controller class: 
app/code/[codePool]/Company/Modulename/controllers/AccountController.php
with the following code:

```
    require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
    class Company_Modulename_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
    {
        public function indexAction()
    {
        die('overriden');
        parent::indexAction();
    }


   }
```

Comment: The only difference between this code and mine is the placement of `AccountController.php` and that this code runs `die()` and then the original method. The problem I'm having is that my action methods aren't being called at all.

Comment: That's something I've begun to wonder, after strewing log statements all over the place now I've noticed that it appears that while I thought `logoutAction` was being called it isn't but I'm clearly getting a 302 redirect after my observer method that triggers on `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_logout` runs. The last thing this method does is set a redirect but this redirect gets ignored and instead I'm redirected to `/customer/account/login`.